# How to save strings in the same column to an array from a txt file in C

Tags: c, string, file, scanf

Suppose I have a txt file that looks like this, where there is only one space between the number and the string:

123 apple

23 pie

3456 water

How can I save apple, pie, and water to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a many solutions for this case, i propose some solutions for reading the string from your file:

1. using `fscanf`, see one example: ``[scanf() and fscanf() in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanf-and-fscanf-in-c-simple-yet-poweful/)
2. using `fgets` to read line by line then using `ssanf` to read the string from each line, see the examples: [sscanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) and [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

For storing the string in an array, you can use the 2D array or the array of char pointer:

```
char str_array[100][256]; // maximum 100 row and max length of each row ups to 256.
// OR
// You have to allocate for two declarations, and do not forget to free when you do not still need to use them  below
char *str_array[100];
char **str_array;
```

For copy string to string, you should use `strcpy` function. Do not use `=` to assign string to string in c.

For example, i use `fscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(!fp) {
        return -1;
    }
    char line[256];
    char array[100][256];
    int a, i = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %255s",&a, line) == 2 && i < 100) {
        strcpy(array[i], line);
        i++;
    }

    // print the array of string
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
        printf("%s\n", array[j]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The input and output:

```
#cat input.txt
123 apple
23 pie
3456 water

./test
apple                                                                                                                   
pie                                                                                                                     
water
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! And may I ask how to save a column if I don't now how many strings are there in one line?

Comment: You can use `strtok` to split the line by space character. Then add the words to 2D array.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I check whether to put the string in array A or array B? @Hitokiri

Comment: i dont understand what is array A or B ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//This code will read all the strings in the file as described
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt","r"); //open file for reading
int n = 3;
char *list[n]; //for saving 3 entities;
int i,a;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    list[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10); //allocating memory
i = 0;
while(!feof(fp))
    fscanf(fp," %d %s",&a,list[i++]);
printf("%s %s %s\n",list[0],list[1],list[2]);
```

Comment: Might be interesting: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I didn't try anything here. Just wanted to let you know that `while(!feof(fp))` may cause issues.